# Hide input if specific input has value

Tags: redux-form, react-admin

I would like to hide input if other input has value. I am using https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input#installation this package which I hope should solve my problem.

I have already tried some combination of usage code provided, but I dont understand how to set it properly.

EDIT note: component={ReferrenceSelectBox} is my custom component

```
const checkRecord = (record) => record.LocationId;
```

```
         <DependentInput resolve={checkRecord}>
            <Field name="ComputerId" label="Computer" source="ComputerId" reference="PC" component={ReferrenceSelectBox}/>
         </DependentInput>
         <Field name="LocationId" label="Location" source="LocationId" reference="Location" component={ReferrenceSelectBox}/>
      </SimpleForm>
```

Basicaly, if ComputerId has value hide LocationId field, if LocationId has value hide ComputerId. It should be easy, but can't figure it out

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The aor-dependent-input package has been removed (react-admin v2.0).
You can achieve a similar effect to the old  component by using the new  component: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with state

```
this.state={
   isRecordExists: record.LocationId;
}
```

and in the return

```
{ this.state.isRecordExists>0 ? 
    <Field name="LocationId" label="Location" source="LocationId" reference="Location" 
    component={ReferrenceSelectBox}/>
    :
    null }
```

basically {statement ? true : false }

I dont know what type of variable comes from "record.LocationId;" but you can modify it.

Comment: And where should i define this state? I am using that field inside form, and it is inside file where are just forms and constants defined

Comment: you can put it in constructor function

Comment: You mean, to create a constructor function and put it inside? I dont have constructor inside this file. It looks like this: [link](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-create-and-edit-components)

Comment: Im using state in class.      export class Main extends Component {...} then i put in constructor() function